# Pritning subarrays in a given array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am a beginner in Java programming and I am trying to print the subarrays in a given array using the concept of recursion.

I am getting my desired result but I am also getting some runtime errors.

My code:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class GFG {
    public static void printArrays(int[] arr, int start,int end,int n){
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+"");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    public static void subArrays(int[] arr, int start, int end,int n) {
        if (end < n) {
            printArrays(arr, start, end, n);
            subArrays(arr, start, end + 1, n);
        }

        if (end >= n) {
            subArrays(arr, start + 1, start + 1, n);
        }

        if (start >= n) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        subArrays(arr, 0, 0, n);
    }
}

The error that I'm getting is this: 


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at GFG.subArrays(GFG.java:16)
    at GFG.subArrays(GFG.java:16)
    at GFG.subArrays(GFG.java:16)
```

The 16th line of code is "subArrays(arr,start+1,start+1,n);"

My output is this:

```
1
12
123
2
23
3
```

Comment: This means you're missing an end condition that will stop the recursion. Either stepping through the code, or (my preference) "playing computer" with paper and pencil, will help you to understand what's happening.

Comment: yes, I understand. But I cannot understand what I am missing.

Comment: Then step through it again; it's short enough it won't take long.

Comment: Recursion, once understood, will become much more intuitive. IMO paper/pencil or stepping through is the fastest way to understand it deeply--and once you do you'll find it in a lot of places. It's not suitable for everything, but when it is, it's like magic.

Comment: I get what you mean. I used to struggle a LOT with recursion, so I decided to start from the very basics and go ahead. I solved some questions with pen and paper for every stage. I then tried to solve questions with my intuition and I have started getting results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you are checking the condition for `return` (i.e. the value of start) at the end but before that, you are already calling `printArrays(arr, start, end, n);`, `subArrays(arr, start + 1, start + 1, n);` and `subArrays(arr, start, end + 1, n);` where the index is going beyond the limit. Put the following check at the beginning of `subArrays`:

```
if (start >= n) {
    return;
}
```

as follows:

```
public static void subArrays(int[] arr, int start, int end, int n) {
    if (start >= n) {
        return;
    }
    if (end < n) {
        printArrays(arr, start, end, n);
        subArrays(arr, start, end + 1, n);
    }    
    if (end >= n) {
        subArrays(arr, start + 1, start + 1, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This removed the error. Thanks a lot.